# java is not recognized as an internal or external command in command prompt when run in normal mode

Tags: java

Java is recognized when used in command prompt(*run as admin*). But when I run Java in command prompt(*without run as admin*), i get the message "Java is not recognized as internal or external command.

- Using windows 10
- java version 1.8_144
- JAVA_HOME and Path variable are set in System Variables

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try to `cd` into the `java\bin` directory?

Comment: Shot in the dark here, have you tried closing all of your command prompt windows and reopening them again ?

Comment: In System variables is Path var including java_home + bin?

Comment: @awgtek Yes in system variables JAVA's path included JAVA_Home+bin however, I have mistakenly set JAVA_HOME variable in User variable instead of System variable. Issue got resolved when I deleted JAVA_HOME from user variables and added a new JAVA_HOME variable in System variables.

Answer (score 2):

In Windows *administrator* and *usual user* work in different environments. Basically, `PATH` system variable should work fine.

But ensure that system variable is not overwritten by user's `PATH` variable (just run command line prompt as usual user and type `echo %PATH%`).

Also, it's possible that incorrect access rights are set on Java's executable (obviously, NTFS is used in Windows 10). I haven't experimented on a real system. But it looks essentially that program will be not found (even it's already in `PATH`) when its directory contents or executable is not accessible for reading/execution for current user.

Comment: Yes your were right. Issue was actually in User Variable. my JAVA_HOME variable was set in User variable. Setting JAVA_HOME in System variable solved the issue.